# Android Studio showing autocomplete for a id which is not anywhere in the project

Tags: android, android-studio

So I have a android project which I am working on, when I try to reference and Edit Text via id "email", it show that I have an object with id "email". If i use it and then built the app it shows this error.

Error:(30, 53) error: cannot find symbol variable email

If that symbol is not there then why is it in the auto complete.
I have tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it, also tried grade sync.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried alot of things (restart Android Studio, PC, Invalidate Caches, Power Saver mode,...).

Finally, deleting **.idea** folder and all **.iml** files from the project, restarting Android Studio and rebuilding gradle did the trick. Autocomplete in XML support library is working again.

Probably checking out files from Version Control or copying all the source files in a new project would do the trick aswell.

Comment: Tried but no luck. Also did findInPath search for the keyword "email" still got nothing. Maybe its a problem with autocomplete. Is there a way for directly jumping to a id's reference in a xml from java code?

Answer (score 0):

So check all this and try to:- *Clean your build, then rebuild *Make
    sure there are no errors or typos in your XML files *Make sure your 
    resource names consist of [a-z0-9.]. Capitals or symbols are not
    allowed for some reason. Perform a Gradle sync (via Tools > Android

> Sync Project with Gradle Files)

---

Comment: He already tried everything you said and moreover, Ids can contain `_` or capital letter.